# Initialize Object with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a class with some data members (int, string, bool, Point).
These data members have public properties {get; set;}.

In my code I create an instance of this class using the default constructor.
So my Object's data members have values of `0`, `string.Empty`, `false`, `{0,0}` respectively.

How do I *initialize* these values of the field data
from an XML file, using LINQ to XML
**without** creating a new instance of the object.

I just want to read in the XML, and set the values of my Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy using Linq to XML. Here's a contrived example, it gets a little tougher if the document is longer and you need to validate the input, but the basic idea is the same

```
var root = XDocument.Parse(@"<data>
<num>3</num>
<str>string</str>
<boo>true</boo>
<point x=""3"" y=""5"" />
</data>").Root;

public class MyObject()
{
  public class Point 
  {
    int X {get;set;}
    int Y  {get;set;}
  }

  public MyObject() {
   Point = new Point();
  }
  public int Num {get;set;}
  public string Str {get;set;}
  public bool Boo {get;set;}
  public Point Point {get; private set;}
}

var myObj = root.Select(new MyObject
{
    Num = int.Parse(root.Element("num").Value),
    Str = root.Element("str").Value,
    Boo = bool.Parse(root.Element("boo").Value),
    Point.X = int.Parse(root.Element("point").Attribute("x").Value),
    Point.Y = int.Parse(root.Element("point").Attribute("y").Value)
});
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but very helpful nonetheless, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is an functional language, which means that you can't use it to mutate data, which is what you are trying to do (change an existing object). **You might want to rethink what you are doing.**

But if you really want to do this inside a LINQ query, you can always create a query that has side effects (not adviced though) by calling a method. Here's an example:

```
static MyObj UpdateMyObj(MyObj obj, int a, string b, 
    bool c, Point d)
{
    obj.A = a;
    obj.B = b;
    obj.C = c;
    obj.D = d;
    return obj;
}
```

Now you can use this method in a `select` clause:

```
MyObj obj = new MyObj();

var q = (
    from x in xml.GetDescendants("root")
    select UpdateMyObj(obj, (int)x.Element("a"), ...))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: If using Linq for this is bad style, then how can I do this nicely?
Editing Object data with info from an xml file without creating a new instance should be posible, no?

Comment: Just don't do it inside a LINQ query. Just retrieve some data using LINQ to XML and inject it into that object.